# How to use with Neo4j with Java simply using JDK Tools?

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm trying to use neo4j embedded in a Java application for a small project of mine. For this, I'm only using JDK Tools, so, there's no Eclipse, Net Beans or IntelliJ IDEA.

I've tried to follow the tutorial supplied by Neo4j ([Include Neo4j in your project](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-setup.html)) , but I'm somehow doing it wrong, since it doesn't work.

To sum up, I've got a small .java file, let's say it's only composed of the bare necessities to work and an import of org.neo4j

```
import org.neo4j; // or org.neo4j.*, or anything else that starts with that

public class Application
{
    // only the bare necessities to work
}
```

I'm trying to compile this simple code with javac using -classpath to specify where to find Neo4j libraries, just like it's showed in the tutorial

```
javac -g -cp "C:/Path/to/libs/Neo4j Community/jre/lib" Application.java
```

But each time, the compilation fail at the line of the import, saying that the package doesn't exist. And of course, once this line is erased, the compilation succeed.

I've already tried to move the libs inside the project's folder, and I've tried to download the neo4j kernel jar and put it inside the Neo4j's folder and the project's folder, but, none of these solutions have worked.

If anyone could help me, I would be very thankful to him.

Cordially,
Jaxon

**EDIT** : When I try to compile with the following command :

```
javac -g -cp "C:\Path\to\libs\Neo4j Community\jre\lib\*" Application.java
```

The error stays and two warnings appear. I don't know if it's related, but here are the errors :

```
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.annotations.ServiceProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.annotations.DocumentationProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
Application.java:4: error: package org.neo4j does not exist
import org.neo4j.*;
^
1 error
2 warnings
```

**EDIT** : I now have a program that compiles, but when I run it, there is an exception that crash the program. The code haven't changed a lot, the only difference is that now I import `org.neo4j.graphdb.*` and `org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.*`

Here is the exception returned :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/GraphDatabaseFactory
    at MyApp.connection(MyApp.java:18)
    at MyApp.<init>(MyApp.java:13)
    at MyApp.main(MyApp.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Well I understand what the exception means but I don't know how to solve the problem. Probably because according to the Neo4j documentation, GraphDatabaseFactory is in org.neo4j.graphdb.factory. So I don't know where to go...

Comment: Try specifying the full path including the jar filename: `javac -cp ".;C:/path/to/lib/neo4j_community.jar" Application.java`

Comment: Nice try, but it didn't work better for me...
Anyway, thanks for the help

Comment: `import org.neo4j` is not legal Java if `neo4j` is a package name.Try something legal. And make sure the Neo4J .jar file is included in your compile-time classpath.

Comment: It seems to work when I import org.neo4j.graphdb.* and compile with the command of cybersam. I will continue to code in order to see if it will work eventually.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `*` wildcard to specify all the jar files in the `lib` folder. Try this:

```
javac -g -cp "C:/Path/to/libs/Neo4j Community/jre/lib/*" Application.java
```

[EDIT]

*Of course, you must use your computer's actual path to the `lib` directory. "C:/Path/to/libs/Neo4j Community/jre/lib/*" is just an example.*

Also, *warnings* like the following (which mean that some parts of the library were annotated to indicate that they support Java 1.7, but you are compiling with Java 1.8) may not prevent the resulting `.class` files from running properly:

```
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.annotations.ServiceProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
```

However, if you want to be sure, one way to get rid of this warning is to downgrade your JDK to 1.7.

Comment: When I tried that, it didn't work either, but two warnings appeared.

I've edited the question for further informations